# Add space to input value after clicking outside of it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have these input boxes in which the values are inserted (all integers). I want them to be shown as these two photos:

**1:**

[image: 1st]

**2:**

[image: 2nd]

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input").each(function() {
    $(this).blur(function() {
      var len = $(this).val().length;


    });
  });

});
```

```css
 .ndInbox {
   background-color: white;
   width: 390px;
   height: 42px;
   box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 #C2C2C2;
   border: none;
   outline: none;
   font-size: 18px;
   margin-bottom: 10px;
   font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
   padding-left: 10px;
 }
 .ndLabel {
   color: #999;
   font-size: 17px;
   font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
 }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="ndLabel" style="position: relative; width: 470px; top:-4px" id="avPurchase03">Average, &euro;:</td>
    <td colspan="2">
      <input id="lpcfIn02Id" class="ndInbox" type="text" value="" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="ndLabel" style="position: relative; width: 470px; top:-4px" id="avNumber03">Budget, &euro;:</td>
    <td colspan="2">
      <input id="lpcfIn03Id" class="ndInbox" type="text" value="" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I've written an incomplete `jQuery` implementation using `blur` but it did not result in the desired functionality. Are my requirements, shown in pictures above, doable?

Thanks in advance.

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/reshadgp/4xcomgyc/)

**UPDATE:**
by clicking outside the input box I also mean if the user tabs to the next field.

Comment: You've shown us everything but your attempt at string manipulation. That's that the question is about, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you just want to convert whatever value is entered into a proper decimal with exactly two digits. You could use the following to accomplish that by using the [`Number()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) function to parse the current value and then formatting it using the [`toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) function :

```
<input class='make-decimal' />
<script>
    $(function(){
        // When an input loses focus...
        $('.make-decimal').blur(function(){
            // Take your value, parse it as a number and output it
            // to exactly two digits
            $(this).val(Number($(this).val()).toFixed(2))
        })
    });
</script>
```

You can [see a live example here](http://jsbin.com/mayehes/edit?html,css,output) and demonstrated below :

[image]

Now as far as adding the spacing between your digits, you could probably use a bit of Regular Expression magic to handle that as seen below :

```
$(function(){
    $('.make-decimal').blur(function(){
        // Get your formatted number (ignore formatting spaces)
        var formatted = Number($(this).val().replace(/\s/g,'')).toFixed(2);
        // Split off any decimal value (there should be one)
        var sections = formatted.split('.');
        // Replace every third digit with a space
        sections[0] = sections[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+\b)/g, " ");
        // Output the updated and rejoined sections
        $(this).val(sections.join('.'));
    });
});
```

which can be [seen here](http://jsbin.com/mayehes/edit?html,output) and demonstrated below :

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's great, but still one more thing, which is spacing between 3 digits.

Comment: I've updated my response to address this issue. Hope it helps :)